# Use Least Upper Bound to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is completee

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> Use Least Upper Bound to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

The following is the proof I did, and it's slightly different from what I see from the book. Can someone check if I'm missing something? Thank you.

**Proof**: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence, and it suffices to show that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. Since sequence is Cauchy, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $m,n\ge N$ implies $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon$. In particular, this means that for all $m\ge N$, $|x_m - x_N|<\epsilon$, which implies that $\{x_m:m\ge N\}$ is bounded above. Thus, it has a supremum $S$.

By definition of supremum, $S-\epsilon<x_m<S$. This shows that $\{x_n\} \to S.$

Am I missing something? I feel like I'm missing something :(

---

The following is in the proof from the book:

> “Let$\{s_k\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $S$ be the set of $y$   such that $s_n < y$ for only finitely many integers $n$.”

I don't see how this comes into work?

Comment: You have identified a different supremum for each $\epsilon$, so it doesn't really make sense to say "$\{x_n\}\to S$." (If you fix an $\epsilon$, as you seem to do to talk about a single $S$, then a sequence like $(-1)^n/n$, with $\epsilon = 1/2$, provides a counterexample. $S_{1/2} = 1/2$, but the sequence obviously does not tend to $1/2$.)

Comment: If $S$ in your book contains $a$ then $s_n\ge a$ eventually. If $(s_n)$ converges to $s$ and $a\in S$ then you should get $s\ge a$. From this you can infer that $\sup S$ is the limit of $(s_n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is good up to here:

"By definition of supremum $S-\epsilon<x_m<S$ " (It should say there exists an $m$ satisfying this, since it is not necessarily true for all $m$).

All that we can know from the above is that there is an $x_m$ that is as close enough to $S$ as required, but this doesn't mean the sequence converges. For example lets consider the following sequence:

$x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is odd and $1$ when $n$ is even. For every $\epsilon$ we can find $a_n$ so that $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$ yet $x_n$ does not converge to $0$.

---

You have taken some steps in the right direction however, perhaps this can get you going. You proved the sequence $x_n$ is bounded, and we know that every bounded sequence has a converging subsequence (hopefully this has been taught).

So the idea for the proof is to take a converging subsequence that converges to $l$ and use this converging subsequence and the fact that $x_n$ is Cauchy to prove $x_n$ converges to $l$ also.

Comment: I edited my post. Would you please take a look? Thanks!